# Where can I download a free audio Tanakh in English?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach

I'm searching for an audio Tanakh in English that I can download for free online. Preferably it should be a non-Western version. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi REH. [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887). Thanks for bringing your question here.

Comment: I've edited your question here, REH, to make it clearer to other users. If for some reason you'd like to revert the changes I've made, you can click the [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/89152/edit) button and put it back the way you like.

Comment: By "non-Western" I assume you mean a recording that is _not_ American. Am I correct?

Comment: [This](http://www.chabad.org/store/audio_bible.htm) might be of interest; however it's not free and doesn't contain the entire Tanach, just the Chumash.

Comment: Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) my answer?

Answer (score 3):

[Jewish Publication Society](https://jps.org/jps-audio-bible/) sells a proprietary recording of its translation, although the weekly portion can be listened [for free](https://jps.org/jps-audio-bible-weekly-portion/) on their site. This [Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jewish.bible.in.english.free) claims to contain the same JPS translation in audio files, even though the provider does not seem to me to be reliable. There are many other free recordings in English, but most of them were not translated by Jews, and may be biased or contain errors.